# Triple-Sytem (Ubuntu Focal Fossa, Win-10, Kubuntu Bionic Beaver): After extending Kubuntu_root-Partition at begin grub2 doesn't recongnize it

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted

i've sometimes changed (extended at the end) partition-sizes with *GParted* without problems, grub2 always found it's entries.
Now i made the mistake to extend an existing Kubuntu_root-Partion to the left by 7GB (shrinking the previous partition at the same amount).
Is it possible, to move the data inside that partition by -7GB with a tool (testdisk or similar)?

Here some infos to the partitions:

```
muelux@LT76A-T430:~$ lsblk --list --fs /dev/sda -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,FSAVAIL,FSUSE%,MOUNTPOINT
NAME  FSTYPE LABEL            FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda                                          
sda1  ntfs   Windows RE tools                
sda2  vfat   SYSTEM            204,6M    20% /boot/efi
sda3                                         
sda4  ntfs   Windows                         
sda5  ntfs                                   
sda6  ext4   Linux_root          5,8G    62% /
sda7  ext4   Linux_home          4,2G    68% /home
sda8  ntfs   Windows_Daten                   
sda9                                         
sda10 ext4   Kubuntu_home                    
muelux@LT76A-T430:~$

muelux@LT76A-T430:~$ sudo lsblk -a /dev/sda
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0   900M  0 part 
├─sda2    8:2    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3    8:3    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda4    8:4    0  48,8G  0 part 
├─sda5    8:5    0   9,8G  0 part 
├─sda6    8:6    0  17,9G  0 part /
├─sda7    8:7    0    16G  0 part /home
├─sda8    8:8    0  24,4G  0 part 
├─sda9    8:9    0  14,7G  0 part 
└─sda10   8:10   0 100,1G  0 part 
muelux@LT76A-T430:~$
muelux@LT76A-T430:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Festplatte /dev/sda: 232,91 GiB, 250059350016 Bytes, 488397168 Sektoren
Festplattenmodell: Samsung SSD 860 
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: gpt
Festplattenbezeichner: CE257587-5BA6-4B2D-80E2-26A0482DF1D5

Gerät         Anfang      Ende  Sektoren  Größe Typ
/dev/sda1       2048   1845247   1843200   900M Windows-Wiederherstellungsumgebung
/dev/sda2    1845248   2377727    532480   260M EFI-System
/dev/sda3    2377728   2639871    262144   128M Microsoft reserviert
/dev/sda4    2639872 105039871 102400000  48,8G Microsoft Basisdaten
/dev/sda5  467916800 488396799  20480000   9,8G Windows-Wiederherstellungsumgebung
/dev/sda6  105039872 142612479  37572608  17,9G Linux-Dateisystem
/dev/sda7  173332480 206772223  33439744    16G Linux-Dateisystem
/dev/sda8  416716800 467916799  51200000  24,4G Microsoft Basisdaten
/dev/sda9  142612480 173332479  30720000  14,7G Linux-Dateisystem
/dev/sda10 206772224 416716799 209944576 100,1G Linux-Dateisystem

Partitionstabelleneinträge sind nicht in Festplatten-Reihenfolge.
muelux@LT76A-T430:~$ 
muelux@LT76A-T430:~$ sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda
[sudo] Passwort für muelux: 
label: gpt
label-id: CE257587-5BA6-4B2D-80E2-26A0482DF1D5
device: /dev/sda
unit: sectors
first-lba: 34
last-lba: 488397134

/dev/sda1 : start=        2048, size=     1843200, type=DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC, uuid=DEDDD5AB-328A-4CDF-8256-84063BEB0224, name="Basic data partition", attrs="RequiredPartition"
/dev/sda2 : start=     1845248, size=      532480, type=C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B, uuid=3B2153CD-763E-4297-8CD1-CC488BD685BE, name="EFI system partition"
/dev/sda3 : start=     2377728, size=      262144, type=E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE, uuid=1C922769-7EA6-469F-9C5A-1A291206795A, name="Microsoft reserved partition"
/dev/sda4 : start=     2639872, size=   102400000, type=EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7, uuid=9A5C8739-84A0-4D26-B619-25A74726F823, name="Basic data partition"
/dev/sda5 : start=   467916800, size=    20480000, type=DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC, uuid=B6CE1215-16A5-43D1-B12C-12C2ADD000EC, name="Basic data partition", attrs="RequiredPartition"
/dev/sda6 : start=   105039872, size=    37572608, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=D2B93336-3CAA-4718-AAED-6FEB010ABA7B, name="/"
/dev/sda7 : start=   173332480, size=    33439744, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=939F1DA1-4806-4DA4-9F57-AAF7EDDD8EFD, name="/home"
/dev/sda8 : start=   416716800, size=    51200000, type=EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7, uuid=A8AF1C1E-F045-4A06-A7D3-38ECC72B5DE9, name="Win_Daten"
/dev/sda9 : start=   142612480, size=    30720000, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=93DF8BCC-95C0-4344-9235-D9192490ABDF, name="/Kubuntu_root"
/dev/sda10 : start=   206772224, size=   209944576, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=FE84EF67-6540-4007-9A82-4A6DB80B52EE, name="/Kubuntu_home"
muelux@LT76A-T430:~$
```

After the grub-update the entry for *Kubuntu_root* has gone, since the entries of the EPT of **/dev/sda9** are now no longer at the start of that partition but +7GB further (Sektor 17620336, rel. to the start of that partition)

[TestDisk-Search (Summary) on sda9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbkhF.png)
[TestDisk-Search (Detail) on sda9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2eHj.png)

Thank's for any advice

Comment: Usually just a small move of a partition, does not change UUID, so it still is the same. This will show a lot of info you already posted. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair What brand/model system?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, @oldfred.

Comment: I've followed your advice, here [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nCPn3nj4Kw/) is the result of _italic_bootrepair which i ran from the still working _italic_Ubuntu Focal Fossa.
The damaged Partition is /dev/sda9, which is expanded to the left by 7GB. So the GPT should be found at (Start of sda9+7GB)?

Comment: `muelux@LT76A-T430:~$ lsb_release -a && uname -r
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
5.4.0-62-generic`

Comment: It is not showing it as ext4? Backup partition table before any changes, so you can get back to current if changes not correct  `sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > PT_sda.txt` I might try testdisk first, but with changes, it finds old versions of partitions, and you have to select correct set of partitions. If you have just an install with just / maybe easier to just reformat & reinstall.  http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk  If not it may be possible to just edit the PT_sda.txt partiiton table & restore it. What does gdisk show? `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`

Comment: I've backed up my partition table, got TestDisk and let it examine the (formerly) Kubuntu_root-Partition (/dev/sda9): It found an EFI System Partition entry (Type 4672?) at sector 17620336. A deeper search reveils a BOOT-dir with the entries BOOTX64.EFI and GRUBX64.EFI, which i saved now.
Should i post the results of gdisk inline or with a link to PasteBin?

Comment: Your ESP is sda2, most do not back up the ESP, but if major issue then have to do a total reinstall of grub. Those files are normally in your ESP, was it at those sector locations? Post in question above.

Comment: To answer your question two posts above: I've worked with that Kubuntu for about half a year and i do have a backup from the _Kubuntu_**home**_ Partition but not from _Kubuntu_**root**_ .  I think, i get in trouble if i try to reinstall Kubuntu with references to my still exiting **_Kubuntu_home_** Partition?

Comment: If you also have exported a list of installed apps & /home if fully functional, you can easily just reinstall to a / (root) partition. Be sure to use Something Else and mount the current partition that is /home. And DO NOT check the format box or you will erase it. Typically with Linux we do not back up system as it is easy to reinstall. I modify only a few files in /etc, which some suggest to also back up. The few I edit, I just copy to /home so normal backup of /home includes those files.

Comment: Thank's @oldfred. 
I loaded Kubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (64-bit), prepared a stick and installed it successfully on /dev/sd9 (with Mountpoint to my former /home-Partition (/dev/sda10) with no formatting.

Comment: After a 'sudo update-grub /dev/sda' the new Ubuntu 20.04 is again in the menue-list.
Now i'm able to start all systems like before; i only have to struggle with the formerly installed programs like _Kontact_ (now _Thunderbird_), _DigiKam_, _Kdenlive_, _Cantana_, _duplicati_, _marble_, _FreeFileSync_ ...
I think, their configuration was at /etc/default/config -> so i lost it?
But thank's a lot, i can use my 100GB of /home-Data as before!

Comment: User application files should be in /home and in .config typically. Firefox & Thunderbird have larger folders in hidden folder .mozilla & .thunderbird. I moved the profiles to my data partition and edit profile.ini to new location. I do keep /home inside / but then it almost is just user configuration files and small. And I regularly houseclean. Only if server application may it be in / & then you need to back that them  up also.

Comment: Yes, I've to do some 'homecleaning', but i first wanted to get my raspi-NAS redundant working. Now I get in another trouble with the 'fresh' installed Kubuntu: after booting the stick I could only choose 'OEM-Installation', so the user 'oem' was created. After login I created my formerly user 'muelux' with admin rights. Now I'm only a member in two groups (muelux and sudo), so I'm not able to manage printers by CUPS for example or to burn a DVD. id
uid=1000(muelux) gid=1000(muelux) Gruppen=1000(muelux),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),116(lpadmin),126(sambashare),132(wireshark)

Comment: My `id` command shows the same as your except I have these. `121(lpadmin),131(lxd),132(sambashare)` Did not install any containers or samba, so not sure what added those. I did add NFS & SSH, so that my be where samba came in. Printer install was automatic for my Brother printer.

Comment: Ok, thank's; at first i did a `sudo usermod -aG lpadmin muelux` so i could manage _CUPS_ again and could add the formerly (at EPSON-Website) loaded _EcoTank_ printer drivers. I think, i could close the question; thanks again for your help!